# Splitting data using time-based splitting in test and train datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, timestamp, train-test-split

I know that `train_test_split` splits it randomly, but I need to know how to split it based on time.

```
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42) 
  # this splits the data randomly as 67% test and 33% train
```

How to split the same data set based on time as 67% train and 33% test? The dataset has a column TimeStamp.

I tried searching on the similar questions but was not sure about the approach.

Can someone explain briefly?

Comment: Do you want a monotonic split -- e.g. the earliest third is test data, and the rest is testing? Or do you want a random split that merely takes time into account, without being a deterministic function of time?

Comment: I want a time based split i.e which splits the data into Train and Test respectively based on Time.

Comment: Is your sampling in time uniform? Is there a constant delay between consecutive samples, or is the delay variable?

Comment: The delay is variable.  One approach I thought is by Sorting by sample based on Time and then split it Train and Test data and then use TimeSeriesSplit in sklearn

Comment: But train_test_split is splitting it randomly as I saw it in its documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On time-series datasets, data splitting takes place in a different way. [See this link](http://francescopochetti.com/pythonic-cross-validation-time-series-pandas-scikit-learn/) for more info. Alternatively, you can try [TimeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) from scikit-learn package. So the main idea is this, suppose you have 10 points of data according to timestamp. Now the splits will be like this :

```
Split 1 : 
Train_indices : 1 
Test_indices  : 2


Split 2 : 
Train_indices : 1, 2 
Test_indices  : 3


Split 3 : 
Train_indices : 1, 2, 3 
Test_indices  : 4

Split 4 : 
Train_indices : 1, 2, 3, 4 
Test_indices  : 5
```

So on and so forth. You can check the example shown in the link above to get a better idea of how TimeSeriesSplit works in sklearn

**Update**
If you have a separate time column, you can simply sort the data based on that column and apply timeSeriesSplit as mentioned above to get the splits.

In order to ensure 67% training and 33% testing data in final split, specify number of splits as following:

```
no_of_split = int((len(data)-3)/3)
```

Example

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4],[1, 2], [3, 4],[3, 4],[1, 2],     [3, 4],[3, 4],[1, 2], [3, 4] ])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=int((len(y)-3)/3))
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

     #To get the indices 
     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

OUTPUT :

```
('TRAIN:', array([0, 1, 2]), 'TEST:', array([3, 4, 5]))
('TRAIN:', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 'TEST:', array([6, 7, 8]))
('TRAIN:', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), 'TEST:', array([ 9, 10, 11]))
```

​

Comment: See, I know TimeSeriesSplit in sklearn but that will only be used once the data is split into Train and Test according to Time not 'randomly' as train_test_split this splits it randomly into Train and Test as per the requirements.

Comment: Is there a library in sklearn which splits data into Train and Test based on time and not randomly or is there any other method?

Comment: Does your data specifically have a 'datetime' column ?

Comment: It has a Time column

Comment: And I am assuming here the time column is not sorted, right ?

Comment: Yes, But I have sorted it in my Sample.

Comment: If it is sorted in that case, you cand directly use time series split. If not, then you need to sort them first then apply time series split. If you want help regarding the latter, just post a sample of the code and dataset so that we can help you out further

Comment: So, I have just one doubt over here as I have sorted it based on Time and after that do I have to just use TimeSeriesSplit(X, y, n_splits=10) and it will split based on Time

Comment: Yes that should do the work. Just sort and split using TimeSeriesSplit

Comment: In to Train and Test Dataset and then no longer I will have to use the function as I mentioned above?

Comment: No, you don't need to use the function you mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Just be careful of TimeSeriesSplit() returns the indices as mentioned in the example

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out and see the results and get back to you after the results.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I have updated the answer based on our comments. If you find this useful, please accept (or upvote) the answer :) Let me know if you need any further help

Comment: But, how will I split my data into train as 67% and 33% test using TimeSeriesSplit?

Comment: Did the answer help you out ?

Comment: Yeah, I got the indices of train and test now how to convert back them into my train and test dataset i.e. how to convert the indices to the train and test data?

Comment: In the same format as like this   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

Comment: In the y_test.shape I'm getting (1,) which is not what I want and I'm not able to plot a confusion matrix as the shape is (1,) and we require(4,) for a binary classification.

Answer (score 19):

One easy way to do it..

First: sort the data by time

Second:

```
import numpy as np 
train_set, test_set= np.split(data, [int(.67 *len(data))])
```

That makes the train_set with the first 67% of the data, and the test_set with rest 33% of the data.

Answer (score 8):

if your data is already sorted based on time then simply use `shuffle=False`

Eg:

`train, test = train_test_split(newdf, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)`

Answer (score 5):

If you have a simple dataset where each row is an observation (e.g. a non-time-series dataset for a classification problem) and you would like to split it into train and test, this function will split into train and test based on a column of dates:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import ceil

def train_test_split_sorted(X, y, test_size, dates):
"""Splits X and y into train and test sets, with test set separated by most recent dates.

    Example:
    --------
    >>> from sklearn import datasets

    # Fake dataset:
    >>> gen_data = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=5)
    >>> dates = np.array(pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=10000, freq='5min'))
    >>> np.random.shuffle(dates)
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(gen_data[0])
    >>> df['date'] = dates
    >>> df['target'] = gen_data[1]

    # Separate:
    >>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split_sorted(df.drop('target', axis=1), df['target'], 0.33, df['date'])

    >>> print('Length train set: {}'.format(len(y_train)))
    Length train set: 8000
    >>> print('Length test set: {}'.format(len(y_test)))
    Length test set: 2000
    >>> print('Last date in train set: {}'.format(X_train['date'].max()))
    Last date in train set: 2016-01-28 18:35:00
    >>> print('First date in test set: {}'.format(X_test['date'].min()))
    First date in test set: 2016-01-28 18:40:00
    """

    n_test = ceil(test_size * len(X))

    sorted_index = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(np.array(dates), np.arange(0, len(dates))), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]
    train_idx = sorted_index[:-n_test]
    test_idx = sorted_index[-n_test:]

    if isinstance(X, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)):
        X_train = X.iloc[train_idx]
        X_test = X.iloc[test_idx]
    else:
        X_train = X[train_idx]
        X_test = X[test_idx]
    if isinstance(y, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)):
        y_train = y.iloc[train_idx]
        y_test = y.iloc[test_idx]
    else:
        y_train = y[train_idx]
        y_test = y[test_idx]

    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

The `dates` argument could actually be any kind of array or Series which you would like to use to sort your data.

In your case, you should call: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split_sorted(X, y, 0.333, TimeStamp)` with `TimeStamp` being the array or column where you have the information about the timestamp of each observation.