# How to split dataset as train and test data into rows using date, pandas and python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, random-forest

How to split dataset as train and test data into rows using date like first 90%(from 2018-01-01 until 2019-02-01) would be train & last 10%(from 2019-02-02 ) would be test data in python?Not splitting randomly?

Comment: I believe this `df_train = df[df['date'] < '2019-02-01']` and this
`df_test = df[df['date'] > '2019-02-02']` should do the trick

Comment: @Louis  this code  --> **from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_features, test_features, train_labels,test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels,test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)** splits the data, i want something similar but splitting the data using date.

Comment: If you order your dataframe by the date and then use `sklearn.train_test_split` with the parameter `shuffle` set to `False` it should allow you to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879915/how-to-split-data-using-time-based-in-test-and-train-respectively/56810887#56810887) you can split it with `np.split`:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.sort_values('date') 
data = df.values
train_set, test_set= np.split(data, [int(.9 * len(data))])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already sorted based on time/date within pandas dataframe then simply use `shuffle=False`

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#target_attribute = df['column_name'] 
#You should drop target column before, you put it into train_test_split. 
#df = df.drop(columns = ['column_name'], axis = 1)

trainingSet, testSet = train_test_split(df,
                                        #target_attribute, 
                                        test_size=0.2,
                                        random_state=42,
                                        #stratify=y,
                                        shuffle=False)
```